# Какая технология используется?

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, angularjs

Добрый вечер, подскажите какая технология используется для открытия изображения https://unsplash.com/new 
По клику на фото открывается фото в полном размере, оно подгружается динамически, что это? ajax?, если кто-то понимает как это работает могли бы вы поделиться своими соображениями как это реализовать.

Answer (score 1):

Там используется технология React.

[Исходники на GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/react)

[Немного примеров кода React](https://github.com/reactjs)

[Курсы по React](https://maxfarseer.gitbooks.io/redux-course-ru/content/)